# resource view/View1.view.xml could not be loaded from resources/view/View1.view.xml. in WebIDE

Tags: resources, sapui5, web-ide

I am getting error "resource view/View1.view.xml could not be loaded from resources/view/View1.view.xml" when I try to load a view from folder "view".
Folder structure in WebIDE is as in below picture.

[image: WebIDE Folder structure :-]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" >
</script>
    <script>
        sap.ui.localResources("webapp");
        var app = new sap.m.App("idApp");
        var view1 = sap.ui.view({id:"idView1", 
        viewName:"view.View1",type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
    </script>
 </head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content" ></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

View1.xml

```
 <mvc:View 
            xmlns="sap.m" 
            xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
<Text id="idbtn" text="Text from" />

</mvc:View>
```

View1.controller

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("View1");

});
```

neo-app.json

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/webapp/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    }
    ]
}
```

error in browser
[image]

I tried several ways and could not find a way to point to View1.xml

Thanks in Advance,
Srini.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `data-sap-ui-resourceroots'{"webapp": "./" }'` inside the script tag and the view name should be `webapp.view.View1` in `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

`sap.ui.localResources("webapp");` registers the webapp folder for the *webapp* namespace. You can see that in the console too.

So it should be `viewName: "webapp.view.View1"`.

Please also note that your controller is then known as *webapp.controller.View1*:

```
return Controller.extend("webapp.controller.View1", {
```

...

Comment: @schnoadel, I change the view name specification according to your suggestion. but still getting the error. I could see the difference in folder path in console but still not working. After the change the path in console is reflected as **webapp/webapp/view/View1.view.xml**.